# How to emit event emitter in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

There is two component List and Modal:

They are not in child - parent relationship.

Problem is when you click on the new button then `openModal()` method is called, you get popup opened. 
And I set `this.isOpenModal = true;`

1. List Component openModal() part of logic:

   ```
   public isOpenModal: boolean = false;

   public openModal(id: string): void {
       if (!this.isOpenModal) {
       this.isOpenModal = true;
       const data = {id: id};
       this.modalModel.add(AudienceModel.ENTITY_NAME, data);
       }
   }
   ```

In the Modal-Component I have close() method:

```
isModalOpen: boolean;

public close(index: number): void {
    this.isModalOpen = false;
    this.audienceModel.isModalOpened = this.isModalOpen;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.modalsArray.length; i++) {
        if (this.modalsArray[index].modalStyle.zIndex <= this.modalsArray[i].modalStyle.zIndex) {
            this.modalsArray[i].modalStyle.zIndex--;
        }
    }
    this.modalsArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```

When close method is exectuted I need this to be setup on false: isOpenModal: boolean = false;
And provide that event in the List Component.

Any idea for solution?

Comment: This `close(index: number)` method is part of a component or a model?

Comment: Part of ModalComponent.

Comment: You should make use of a service which acts as intermediate between these components, so these components are loosely couples. The service takes care of showing and closing the modal. You can use this service to emit values using `RxJS Subject` when the modal is closed.

Comment: how is isOpenModal modal being used? In an ngIf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a shared service like :

`shared.service.ts` :

declare a Subject :

```
openModalSubject : Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>() ;

setModalStatus(isOpenModal : boolean){
 openModalSubject.next(isOpenModal);
}
```

Now you can subscribe to the subject in your component after using the setter like this :

`this.sharedService.setModalStatus(isOpenModal);` .

As soon as you set , the subject will publish the `isOpenModal` to your component where it is subscribed .

in your component , inject the `shared.service.ts` and you can subscribe like :

```
this.sharedService.openModalSubject.subscribe((openModal: boolean) => {
 //do whatever you want with the openModal 
});
```

Comment: Why would you create a Subject in the service not just declare it as a normal boolean?  Basically why would I do openModalSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>()  instead of openModalSubject: boolean?

Comment: @AustinBorn using a subject , you can have multiple components listen to the status of modal . If you just declare it as boolean how will you notify your component the status of modal ?

Comment: @CruelEngine If the components are referencing the same variable from the shared service, is there a need to notify the other? The values would be the same in either component if the service is global.

Comment: @AustinBorn if you do not notify how would you expect the other component know about the status change ?

Comment: @AustinBorn Even if your service is global there is no way you can tell your component that the value stored by the service has changed unless an event has been emitted which the subject does for us if you've subscribed to it

Comment: @CruelEngine Why does the other component need to know if the value is changed as long as it changes? I&#39;m not understanding the purpose of using a Subscription when it could be done in a simpler way.

Comment: @AustinBorn A component can have many functionalities that needs to be run when the value changes and a simple reference to variable is not enough to do that :) . This  example will help you : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmigvu . Please observe the console logs. Also if there is a simple way please help me out with an example .

Answer (score 2):

Are those two component in `child - parent` relationship?

If so, you can just use `input - output` method.

In child component:

```
@Output() modalClosed: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
...
this.closed.emit(true);
```

In parent template:

```
<modal-selector (modalClosed)="onModalClose($event)"></modal-selector>
```

In parent component:

```
onModalClose($event) { */ do something when modal closes /* }
```

Comment: They are not in parent - child relationship.
Thanks on the answer.

Comment: Can I by service emit that event between this two component ?

Comment: Sure, in that case you should make a shared service of some kind with almost the same approach, but with a little bit more code. This should help: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: No problem. Sretno!

Answer (score 2):

I think your query seems somewhat unclear but i am answering according to your question title

you can create an instance of event emitter like this

```
eventEmit = new EventEmitter<your- model>();
```

Now you can emit this event using emit function:-

```
this.eventEmit.emit(here pass the values you want to pass);
```

in the component where you want to listen to it use the subscribe () method to listen to event.

Comment: No they are not in child - parent.
Can I by service emit that event between this two component ?

Comment: yes, you can emit a event in a service too. The syntax is similar